# Relacionar 3 tablas (HashSet) Hbm

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Intento llegar a un campo en una tabla y no sé cómo hacerlo. Tengo una tabla donde tengo todos los datos (TespEolReference), tengo otra tabla intermedia que se llama tabla EolMedia donde está el hashset hacia TespTaxon y el campo taxonRecordId, que es el campo que estoy interesado en actualizar. Lo estoy desarrollando para crear un nuevo registro. Me deja actualizar los registros que ya hay en BBDD pero al ingresar uno nuevo no lo muestra en el formulario ya que no esta guardando el id necesario y relacionado. Dejo mi código para que lo veas.

Gracias a todos chicos!

**TespEolReferenceData.java**

```
 * TespEolReference generated by hbm2java
 */
public class TespEolReferenceData  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private String idreference;
     private TespTPublicationtype tespTPublicationtype;
     private String fullReference;
     private Set<TespEolmedia> tespEolmedias = new HashSet(0);
     private BigDecimal idtaxon;
     private String scientificname;
}
```

**TespEolReference.java**

```
public class TespEolReference extends AbstractGenericEntity implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Long idreference;
    private TespTPublicationtype tespTPublicationtype;
    private String fullReference;
    private Set tespEolmedias = new HashSet(0);
}
```

**TespEolMedia.java**

```
public class TespEolmedia extends AbstractGenericEntity implements java.io.Serializable {

private BigDecimal idmedia;
private TespTAudience tespTAudience;
private TespTType tespTType;
private Set tespTaxons = new HashSet(0);
private Set tespEolReferences = new HashSet(0);
}
```

**TespTaxon.java**

```
public class TespTaxon extends AbstractGenericEntity implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private BigDecimal taxonid;
    private TespTAmbitos tespTAmbitos;
    private BigDecimal taxonrecordid;
    private BigDecimal idtaxonomicstatus;
    private String source;
    private String tmpDatasetid;

    private Set<TespEolmedia> tespEolmedias = new HashSet<TespEolmedia>(0);
    private Set<TespEolReference> testEolReference = new HashSet<TespEolReference>(0);
}
```

**ApplicationServiceUtils.java**

```
public static TespEolReference getTespEolReference(
            TespEolReferenceData tespEolReferenceData) {

        try {

            TespEolReference tespEolReference = new TespEolReference();

            if(tespEolReferenceData.getIdreference() != null && !tespEolReferenceData.getIdreference().equals("")) {
                tespEolReference.setIdreference(new Long(tespEolReferenceData.getIdreference()));
            }

            tespEolReference.setFullReference(tespEolReferenceData.getFullReference());


            **if(tespEolReferenceData.getIdtaxon() != null && !tespEolReferenceData.getIdtaxon().equals("")) {
            //  TespEolmedia tespEolmedia = new TespEolmedia();

                TespTaxon tespTaxon = new TespTaxon();
                tespTaxon.setTaxonrecordid(new BigDecimal(tespEolReferenceData.getIdtaxon()));

                HashSet tespTaxons = new HashSet();
                tespTaxons.add(tespTaxon);
                tespEolReference.setTespEolmedias(tespTaxons);
            }**

            return tespEolReference;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Ha ocurrido un error en getTespEolReference: " 
                    + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static TespEolReferenceData getTespEolReferenceData(
            TespEolReference tespEolReference) {

        try {

            TespEolReferenceData tespEolReferenceData = new TespEolReferenceData();

            tespEolReferenceData.setIdreference(tespEolReference.getIdreference().toString());

            tespEolReferenceData.setFullReference(tespEolReference.getFullReference());



            return  tespEolReferenceData ;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Ha ocurrido un error en getTespEolReferenceData: " 
                    + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**TespEolReference.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="es.magrama.iepnb.especies.bom.hibernate.tables.TespEolReference" table="TESP_EOL_REFERENCE" schema="DBA_IEPNB">
        <id name="idreference" type="long">
            <column name="IDREFERENCE" precision="22" scale="0" />
            <generator class="sequence-identity" >
                <param name="sequence">SEQ_TESP_EOL_REFERENCE</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="tespTPublicationtype" class="es.magrama.iepnb.especies.bom.hibernate.tables.TespTPublicationtype" fetch="select">
            <column name="IDPUBLICATIONTYPE" precision="22" scale="0" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="fullReference" type="string">
            <column name="FULL_REFERENCE" />
        </property>
        <property name="primarytitle" type="string">
            <column name="PRIMARYTITLE" />
        </property>
        <property name="title" type="string">
            <column name="TITLE" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**TespEolMedia.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="es.magrama.iepnb.especies.bom.hibernate.tables.TespEolmedia" table="TESP_EOLMEDIA" schema="DBA_IEPNB">
        <id name="idmedia" type="big_decimal">
            <column name="IDMEDIA" precision="22" scale="0" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <set name="tespTaxons" table="TESP_TAXON_EOL_MEDIA" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="IDMEDIA" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <many-to-many entity-name="es.magrama.iepnb.especies.bom.hibernate.tables.TespTaxon">
                <column name="TAXONID" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true" />
            </many-to-many>
        </set>
        <set name="tespEolReferences" table="TESP_EOLMEDIAEOLREFERENCE" inverse="false" lazy="false" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="IDMEDIA" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <many-to-many entity-name="es.magrama.iepnb.especies.bom.hibernate.tables.TespEolReference">
                <column name="IDREFERENCE" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true" />
            </many-to-many>
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**TespTaxon.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 26-ago-2016 9:41:02 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="es.magrama.iepnb.especies.bom.hibernate.tables.TespTaxon" table="TESP_TAXON" schema="DBA_IEPNB" lazy="true" >
        <id name="taxonid" type="big_decimal">
            <column name="TAXONID" precision="22" scale="0" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="tespPliniancoreExtension" class="es.magrama.iepnb.especies.bom.hibernate.tables.TespPliniancoreExtension" lazy="false" fetch="select">
            <column name="TAXONRECORDID" precision="22" scale="0" />
        </many-to-one>

        <set name="tespEolmedias" table="TESP_TAXON_EOL_MEDIA" inverse="false" lazy="false" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="TAXONID" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <many-to-many entity-name="es.magrama.iepnb.especies.bom.hibernate.tables.TespEolmedia">
                <column name="IDMEDIA" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true" />
            </many-to-many>
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: es posible que te falte el setTespTPublicationtype en TespEolReference, entonces en esa tabla no acepta nulo en ese campo y por eso no puedas crear el nuevo registro

Comment: @sirdaiz me guarda en bbdd el registro nuevo pero no me devuelve nada en la vista ya que tiene que recuperar un objeto(taxonRecordId) de otra tabla distinta.

Comment: es posible q cuando por ejm hagar un modelandview("list",result), supongo que en ese result tendras por ejm 6 objetos pero tu esperas 7, por lo que en el momento de recuperar ese result ese objeto que te falta estara cascando y por eso no lo añade